# JSX list of SharePoint list attachments not displaying when using map to render

Tags: reactjs, file, spfx

I'm trying to display a list of attached file names using JSX/React/TypeScript.
Here's the function which is successfully retrieving the files. I'm storing them in a variable and also setting them into state (I've tried both ways by experimenting).

```
let theFiles = null;

const getAttachedFiles = async () => {

        let item = await Utils.ReadListItem("MyList", Id);
        item.attachmentFiles.get().then(v => {

            theFiles = v.map(file => file.FileName);
            console.log(theFiles, 'theFiles');
            setAttachedFiles(theFiles);
            console.log(attachedFiles, 'attachedFiles');
     
        });
    };
```

Here's the JSX:

```
  <div>
   {theFiles.map((file, index) =>
   <li key={index}>{file}</li>)}
  </div>
```

The list is not displaying at all. I've set the mapped list of items into state but because of async, it's not updating in time of render. Also setting the list of files to a variable doesn't work either.

UPDATE: I didn't mention i'm using TypeScript and this was the issue. Here is what I did for the benefit of anyone struggling with TypeScript like me:

```
const [attachedFiles, setAttachedFiles] = useState<Array<IAttachmentInfo>>(null);
...........
const getAttachedFiles = () => {
        Utils
            .ReadListItem("MyList", Id)
            .then(item => {
                item.attachmentFiles
                    .get()
                    .then(setAttachedFiles);
            });
    };
...........

  {attachedFiles ? attachedFiles.map((attachedfile, index) =>
                        <li key={index}>
                            {attachedfile.FileName}
                        </li>
                    ) : null}
```

I added the <Array> Type to the state. This solved the problem. The issue was I was retrieving a `string[]` into the `theFiles` variable and it was expecting something more specific given by the Type.

Comment: It looks like you aren't mapping the files from your state value, you're just using `theFiles` (from `let theFiles = null`) - Try instead mapping whatever state value `setAttachedFiles` sets (maybe `attachedFiles.map()`?)

Comment: It only returns null if I try that. I do successfully receive the filenames as an array. I have tried setting the map directly into state and using useEffect with a dependency array, which successfully shows the attached files but it's running an infinite loop.....